# C++ GUI freezes during communication over socket thread with Python

Tags: python, c++, multithreading, sockets, tcp

First of all I want to mention that I've gone through a lot of socket threading tutorials before attempting to integrate it into my own GUI, but I still consider myself fairly new to the subject.

I have a server written in python that opens a socket and starts a thread over localhost, and listens over the port for a client:

```
def StartThread():
     tcpsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
     tcpsock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
     tcpsock.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
     threads = []
     tcpsock.listen(5)
     print "Waiting for incoming connections from client..."
     (conn, (ip,port)) = tcpsock.accept()
     print 'Got connection from ', (ip,port)
     newthread = ClientThread(ip,port,conn, 1)
     newthread.start()
     return newthread
```

Here is the ClientThread class:

```
class ClientThread(Thread):

     def __init__(self,ip,port,sock, status):
         Thread.__init__(self)
         self.ip = ip
         self.port = port
         self.sock = sock
         self.status = 1
         print " New thread started for "+ip+":"+str(port)
```

After I run the server code, I click a button on my C++ GUI which runs the client code StartConnection() based off the Microsoft Winsock client template.

```
void CPSR_CRSDlg::OnBnClickedInit2()
{
    if(!checkTimerStarted())
    // Set mmtimer to aquire the data
    {
        m_ntimerID = timeSetEvent(  TIMERINTRRVAL,                               
                                    1,                                   
                                    timerHandler,                         
                                    0,                        
                                    TIME_PERIODIC);  
        SetTimer(1,TIMERINTRRVAL_2,NULL); 
        m_bTimer_started = true;

    }
    StartConnection();
}
```

The connection does start successfully and the python code prints the address of the connection and the thread, but then my GUI freezes, so that I can't click any of the other buttons to actually send data over the connection.

Why does my application freeze? Am I not instantiating the thread correctly?

The StartConnection() code is off the msdn website but here is my slightly modified version if needed:

```
void StartConnection(){ 
    //printf("Connection Starting... \n");
    WSADATA wsaData;
    ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    struct addrinfo *result = NULL,
                    *ptr = NULL,
                    hints;

    int argc = 2;

    // Validate the parameters
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("usage: %s server-name\n", "client");
        return;
    }

    // Initialize Winsock
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        return;
    }

    ZeroMemory( &hints, sizeof(hints) );
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

    // Resolve the server address and port
    //iResult = getaddrinfo(argv[1], DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
    iResult = getaddrinfo("localhost", DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
    if ( iResult != 0 ) {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return;
    }

    // Attempt to connect to an address until one succeeds
    for(ptr=result; ptr != NULL ;ptr=ptr->ai_next) {

        // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
        ConnectSocket = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype, 
            ptr->ai_protocol);
        if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
            WSACleanup();
            return;
        }

        // Connect to server.
        iResult = connect( ConnectSocket, ptr->ai_addr, (int)ptr->ai_addrlen);
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            closesocket(ConnectSocket);
            ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result);

    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("Unable to connect to server!\n");
        WSACleanup();
        return;
    }
    return;
}

void StopConnection(){
    closesocket(ConnectSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return;
}

void SendJointValues(double *joints){
    iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
    j = parseJSON(joints[0],joints[1],joints[2],joints[3], \
        joints[4],joints[5]);
    int x = send(ConnectSocket, j, strlen(j), 0);
    //iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
}
```

**Edit:**

The GUI does respond again after I send data via the server, and the client then successfully sends back one iteration of data. But after this exchange the GUI freezes again until more data is sent.

Here is the send+receive portion of the server:

```
def receiveData(self):
    while (self.status == 1):
        joints = [0,0,0,0,0,0]
        self.sock.sendall('send')
        print "Data Sent!"
        data = self.sock.recv(4096)
        print "Data received: ", data
        self.checkStatus(data)
        print "Status is: ", self.status

        if (self.status == 1):
            data_loaded = json.loads(data)
            joints = self.createJointArr(data_loaded['Joints'])
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print joints
            return joints
```

And the SendJointValues() in the client is called in this Timer function:

```
void CPSR_CRSDlg::OnTimer(UINT_PTR nIDEvent)
{

    CString str;
    long Position;
    double engPosition;
    double dblPosition;
    double dblSpeed;
    bool ret;

    // Arch
    USB4_01.Controller_3.getEncoderPosition(Position);
    countTodegree(Position,engPosition,ARCH);
    str.Format(_T("%10.2f"),engPosition);
    m_staPosArch.SetWindowText(str);

    // Wrist Pitch
    USB4_01.Controller_2.getEncoderPosition(Position);
    countTodegree(Position,engPosition,TILT);
    str.Format(_T("%10.2f"),engPosition);
    m_staPosPitch.SetWindowText(str);

    // Linear
    USB4_02.Controller_1.getEncoderPosition(Position);
    countTodegree(Position,engPosition,LINEAR);
    str.Format(_T("%10.2f"),engPosition);
    m_staPosLinear.SetWindowText(str);

    // Turret
    USB4_02.Controller_2.getEncoderPosition(Position);
    countTodegree(Position,engPosition,TURRET);
    str.Format(_T("%10.2f"),engPosition);
    m_staPosTurret.SetWindowText(str);

    // Roll
    USB4_02.Controller_4.getEncoderPosition(Position);
    countTodegree(Position,engPosition,ROLL);
    str.Format(_T("%10.2f"),engPosition);
    m_staPosRoll.SetWindowText(str);

    // Drill/Tool
    USB4_02.Controller_3.getEncoderPosition(Position);
    countTodegree(-Position,engPosition,DRILL);
    str.Format(_T("%10.2f"),engPosition);
    m_staPosDrill.SetWindowText(str);

    // For Penetrate joint
    if(JntPenetration.isInitialized())
    {
        // Get Position feedback
        ret = JntPenetration.getPosition(dblPosition); 
        if(ret) // get position feedback successfully
        {
            Position = (long) dblPosition;
            countTodegree(Position,engPosition,PENETRATE);
            str.Format(_T("%10.2f"),engPosition);
            m_staPosPenetrate.SetWindowText(str);
            m_dCurentPentrationPosition = engPosition;
        }
        // Get Speed feedback;
        if(m_bDrilling_started)
        {
            // Penetration position close enough AND At least on cycle reached
            if( (abs(engPosition - m_dDrilling_target_position) < 0.1) &&(m_Direction_Changed == true))
                m_bPenetrationStopped = true;
            else
                m_bPenetrationStopped = false;
            //JntPenetration.getSpeed(dblSpeed); 
            //if(dblSpeed < .05 )
            //  m_bPenetrationStopped = true;
            //else
            //  m_bPenetrationStopped = false;      
        }

    }

    SendJointValues(JointArray);

    // For drilling motion control
    if(m_bDrilling_started)
        drilingProcedure();

    CDialog::OnTimer(nIDEvent);
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with this.  When you attach a debugger to the client when it is frozen and break all, what is on the call stack of the client threads?

Comment: (1) ntdll.dll!7717c27c()  

(2) [Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for ntdll.dll] 
 (3) KernelBase.dll!76b02cc7()  
 (4) KernelBase.dll!76b02c02()  
 (5) USB4.dll!5c6c5d9c()  
 (6) USB4.dll!5c6c653f()  
 (7) USB4.dll!5c6c190d()  
 (8) USB4.dll!5c6c1ab2()  
 (9) USB4.dll!5c6c2545()  
> PSR_CRS.exe!USB4_US_Motor_Controller::updateEncoder()  Line 58 + 0x19 bytes C++
 (10) PSR_CRS.exe!USB4_US_Motor_Controller::controller()  Line 262 C++

Comment: (11) PSR_CRS.exe!timerHandler(unsigned int id=16, unsigned int msg=0, unsigned long dwUser=0, unsigned long dw1=0, unsigned long dw2=0)  Line 566 C++
 (12) winmm.dll!6ea24909()  
 (13) kernel32.dll!76457c04()  
 (14) ntdll.dll!7719ab8f()  
 (15) ntdll.dll!7719ab5a()

Comment: Most likely your SendJointValues() function is blocking inside the recv() call, waiting for some data to come in from the TCP socket, and that data never comes, hence the freeze.  (One of the calls to connect() might also be a culprit for blocking, although that is less likely)

Comment: I put numbers beside each line because I was unable to format it correctly

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I think you're right, Ill edit my post to update the fact that the GUI gets back responsiveness for the fraction of time that the Python server sends data, but then freezes again